# C++ Sectioning and Comparing a 2d Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I'm working on problem for a class that requires we use 2d dynamic arrays to get integers as each entry per array 'block' and save it. It must be able to take any size of array, all of which gets inputted from the user when the program gets ran. 
Then, the entries in the array are to be sorted by each 3x3 section in the array, and the sum of the largest 'section' is to be returned.

I haven't had a problem with allocating memory and assigning integers, and I also have it set up to delete and return all of the dynamic memory when the program completes, but I can't figure out how to access every 3x3 section of the array. I can only access the first one to add together, without using a loop. Which I'm pretty sure I'll need a loop to get to all of the data.

How would I go about accessing, summing, and comparing each 3x3 section of the array?

Here's a part of what I have so far;

```
  int sumGrid = 0;

  // this will get the 1st 3x3's sum correct
  sumGrid = (grid[i][j] + grid[i+1][j] + grid[i+2][j] + grid[i][j+1]
             + grid[i+1][j+1] + grid[i+2][j+1] + grid[i][j+2]
             + grid[i+1][j+2] + grid[i+2][j+2]);

  // this part isn't right though
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
      if(((i+1)<height)&&((i+2)<height)&&((j+1)<width)&&((j+2)<width))
        {
          int tempGrid = 0;
          tempGrid = (grid[i][j] + grid[i+1][j] + grid[i+2][j] + grid[i][j+1]
                + grid[i+1][j+1] + grid[i+2][j+1] + grid[i][j+2]
                + grid[i+1][j+2] + grid[i+2][j+2]);
          if(tempGrid < sumGrid)
            sumGrid = tempGrid;
        }
      else break;
    }
  }
  biggestGrid = sumGrid;
```

Any help or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You are on the right track, I'd recommend drawing the array out on paper and labeling each index. It helped me alot when I was doing something similar for a parallel class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loops, you access elements i+1 and i+2 as well as j+1 and j+2. However, towards the edges of the array, it will get out of bound.

To resolve this, you need the array to stop at height-2 and width-2 instead of height and width.